# Is there any possible way to avoid ThreadAbortException when using thread.abort() method?

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadabortexception

I have created multiple thread. It is doing some big task. After some I aborted the all thread, but sometime it is raising the threadabortexception. I want to avoid it from occuring.

Comment: *Not* using `Thread.Abort` will work pretty well for avoiding `ThreadAbortException`. Thread signaling and cooperative cancellation are better alternatives in a *vast* majority of use cases.

Comment: Plenty of articles written on the topic. Here's one: http://blogs.msmvps.com/peterritchie/2007/08/22/thead-abort-is-a-sign-of-a-poorly-designed-program/

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. That's how thread aborts work.

Do not abort the thread. Terminate it in a cooperative, well-defined fashion. Thread aborts cause *all kinds* of nasty issues.